# Plotly Draw line according to an equation

Tags: javascript, plot, equation, plotly

I would like to drow a line according to an equation, for example: y=2x+3.

Is there any way to do this in plotly javascript (or python) without having to sample the equation at different points?

Comment: I am not sure what plotty is, but you could do this in javascript and html5 canvas. Let me know if you would like to try that route, and an example.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible in the way you are asking for. `plotly` just visualizes some arrays of data and these arrays can be obtained in different ways: e.g. by querying some database or by calculating with equation. But if you want to use equation, you have to calculate appropriate `x` and `y` arrays (or `x`, `y` and `z` in case of 3D plots) and then send it to `plotly`.

Here is example in Python (Jupyter Notebook):

```
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
import numpy as np
init_notebook_mode()

x = np.linspace(-2, 3)
iplot([{'x': x, 'y': x**2}])
```

[image: Parabola]

If this is inappropriate way to do this for you, I believe it worth to expand a question and explain why.